# Is there an alternative shorter translation for this string?

Tags: translation

I had an application I wrote translated into german from english, and I got the following.

> Over these next few steps, [somename] will guide you through customizing your new copy of [somename2].

to

> Mit den nächsten Schritten wird [somename] Ihnen helfen, Ihre neue Kopie von [somename2] nach Ihren Bedürfnissen anzupassen.

I'm sure the translation is fine, however the string is a little long for me to incorporate.

Is there a shorter alternative to this?

Comment: The "nach Ihren Bedürfnissen" can be dropped. There should be a comma after "helfen".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say

> Im Folgenden hilft 'somename' Ihnen schrittweise dabei, Ihre Kopie (von) 'somename2' anzupassen/zu individualisieren.

or maybe

> 'somename' führt Sie (nun) schrittweise durch den Anpassungsprozess für Ihre Kopie (von) 'somename2'

Comment: Das "von" vor 'somename2' sollte aber stehen bleiben. Ich nehme an, 'somename2' ist der Name des Programms.

Comment: @PMF Richtig, "somename2 'ist der Name des Programms

Comment: Ich dachte dabei an ein Office-Dokument oder so etwas in der Art. In meinem Kopf hat es auch ohne von funktioniert, hab's mal in Klammern dazugesetzt. Kann durchaus sein, dass es ohne "von" komisch klingen könnte.

Comment: I would drop or replace the *Kopie (von).* This is a one-to-one translation from English, which is not used in German. Alternatives: »ihre Ausgabe/Version von«, or just »den Anpassungsprozess für somename2«.